# Need a sample step function to orchestrate multiple API gateway calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I need a step function example for orchestrate few flows in my functions.
Sync all credit/debit using API call --> Update account balance API call -->send notification in case of debit with updated balance

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a step function that can invoke a Lambda function. This Lambda function would call your API Gateway endpoint.

There is a tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/) that should help to demonstarte how to build a workflow using Lambda functions.

You can also find many sample projects [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/create-sample-projects.html).